# Changing Facebook Messenger colors to custom ones

Tags: facebook, colors, facebook-messenger

Because MAUF app has been dead since July 2017, I was looking for another way of changing colors in facebook messenger to the ones I want. Found something here: http://wanna-be.pro/facebook_messenger_dialog_color/

I succesfully intercepted XHR request, managed to change it a bit (color) and sent the modified version back to Facebook. Unfortunately, nothing happened.
I tried playing with it a little bit more, and noticed it changes color only if the specified color is one of the 15 facebook offers us to change in a normal way.

Is there any way to set a custom color now, or has the facebook changed it in a way it's not possible by any method now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook fixed this by checking to see if the requested color matches the pre-approved colors.

This is server-side, so there's no way to change this except the black color on secret conversations. There's no way around it. Unfortunately, we have to suck it up with the garbage suggested ones.